# Permutation of lengthy string

Tags: algorithm, math

The following is the question I tried solving :

> A string contains characters from '0' to '9'. Now  find out the total possible permutations for this string. Since the number can be very large, output the number modulus 10^9+7.
>
> > Input : 
> >     First line represent the number of test cases(T).
> >     Each test case contains a string of digits.
> >     Output : 
> >     For each test case output the required result.
> >
> > Constraints :
> >     T<=100. Length of String <= 1000

So, I assumed that I just need to find out len! where len is the length of the string. 
My code for finding out the factorial is as follows :

```
long long int fact(long long int n)
{
if(n<=1)
return 1;
else
return (len * fact(len-1))%1000000007;
}
```

But I keep getting WA for this code. Disregarding the Output format issues, is the above code for finding out the factorial correct? Or should I use a different approach?

NOTE: I also changed the algorithm so that repetition of certain characters is handled by dividing the answer by the product of factorial of the occurrences of each character.

Comment: it's more of a maths question. the hint is: "Since the number can be very large, output the number modulus 10^9+7."

Comment: The algorithm is wrong. Try out some small cases by hand and try to find one where your algorithm breaks. Specifically make sure you are clear on the definition of a permutation.

Answer (score 4):

(a) It's not just `n!`, there are only 10 possible digits (and possibly fewer in your string). If I gave you the string `"22"`, there would only be 1 permutation.

(b) The ultimate number is still going to be very large, you aren't going to be able to calculate it without bignums. But since you only need the number modulo a reasonably small number, you can use identities for mod to keep intermediate numbers small. Of particular use will be the fact that `a * b % k = ((a % k) * (b % k)) % k`.

Hopefully this is enough to go on without spoiling it.

Comment: Yeah, I resolved the first issue by handling duplicates. But I don't get what exactly you mean by (b).

Comment: @user3159871 the point is that you will calculate your number as a sum\product(the above formula holds also for addition, you can find more formulas [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Equivalencies)) of other numbers, meaning if you know that your total is of the form `a *b` and `a=234567` and `b=1234532213` for example, both numbers can be stored on 32bits, while the product can't, so to avoid their multiplication to get `n mod m`, you apply the above formula i.e. doing operations separately on `a` and `b` which are ints.